# SQL Log, can I delete this file? SQLDump10000.txt

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, sql

I want to know if I can delete this : SQLDump10000.txt . It's taking too much space.

If I delete it will it corrupt the database?

Comment: On a server, the answer to "Can I delete it?" is **always** "Not unless you know who/what put it there, and why." Then you can make an informed decision yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete it without corrupting the DB. However, you should try to find who created the dump and why (likely a partial or full backup, though a strange way to do so), and ascertain if it is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like a SQL Server dump file to me - if it's recent then be cautious, as it most likely means SQL Server had a problem. It might re-occur. Have a good look in the SQL and NT logs at around the time of the dump file date. Also, pay extra attention to your backups (you do test them?)